# laravel : BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method detach does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables

- `users`
- `groups`
- `group_user` (a pivot table which handles the membership of users in groups)

I am trying to delete the membership of a user from a group like this:

```
public function userDelete (Request $request, $userId)
{
    $gid = $request->group;
    $group = Group::find($gid);
    $user = User::find($userId);

    $user->groups->detach();

    // and the second method is :
    // foreach ($group->users as $user) {
    //     if ($user->pivot->user_id == $userId) {
    //         $user->detach($gid);
    //         
    //         break;
    //     }
    // }
}
```

I have tried it in may ways, but it always gives the error that the method `detach()` is not found:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
>       Method detach does not exist.

Comment: I seen the document is  `$user->roles()->detach($roleId);` ,have you try `$user->groups()->detach();` ?

Comment: could you post your user and group models

Answer (score 4):

When you do **$user->groups->detach()**, you call **detach()** on the resulting groups collection.

Instead, you should call the **detach()** method on the relation:

```
$user->groups()->detach();
```